# Continuous linear image which is a proper subspace must be the null space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of Theorem 3.5 in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

The context is: $M$ is a subspace of a locally convex space $X$, and $T$ is a continuous linear functional in the dual $X^*$. The claim that I'm having trouble seeing is:

> Since $T(M)$ is a proper subspace of the scalar field, we must have
>   $T(M) = \{0\}.$

Why is this? I know that every non-zero subspace must be unbounded... is $T(M)$ bounded for some reason that I don't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T(M)\ne\{0\}$, say, $c\in T(M)$, $c\ne 0$, say, $T(x)=c$, then for every scalar $a$, $T(ac^{-1}x)=ac^{-1}T(x)=ac^{-1}c=a$, then $a\in T(M)$ since $ac^{-1}x\in M$, so $T(M)$ is the whole scalar field, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. So we didn't need local convexity here. Is there some general way of stating this result?

Comment: Actually all the topological properties are redundant.

Comment: So the question can be like: $M$ is a vector subspace of $X$, and $T$ is an algebraic linear functional, if $T(M)$ is a proper vector subspace of the scalar field, then $T(M)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. The scalar field just has two subspace: itself and $\{0\}$. This is completely obvious when I think about $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Yes, that is right.